# Optimal number of actor instances(threads) needed to load document on solr cloud

Tags: multithreading, solr, akka, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a situation where I need to load documents from my app (**in millions**) into **solr cloud with zookeeper as a configuration synchronization service **. I am stuck with the performance issues due to lot of incoming document flux. Let's say I have two shards of solr running and two instances of zookeeper host for each shard. So my approach is something like this :

```
  var rtr = system.actorOf(Props(new solrCloudActor(zkHost,core)).withRouter(SmallestMailboxRouter(nrOfInstances = 8)))
  //router vector created globally with 8 instances based on some black box tests that single solr instance can utilize 8 threads in parallel for loading.
  .
  ..
  ... 
  val doc:SolrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument() //repeated million times depending on number of documents and creating docs here
  doc.addfield("key","value")
  .
  ...
  rtr ! loadDoc(doc) // broadcasting the doc here 

class solrCloudActor(zkHost:String,solrCoreName:String) extends Actor{
  val server:CloudSolrServer  = new CloudSolrServer(zkHost)
  server.setDefaultCollection(solrCoreName)
  def recieve{
    case loadDoc(d:SolrInputDocument) => server.add(d)
  }
}
```

My few concerns here :

1. Is this approach correct .Actually this made sense when I had single instance of solr and created 8 **router vector instances of httpclient actor** instead of **solrcloud with zookeeper** .
2. What is the optimal number of threads needed to make the solr loading at its peak when I have millions of documents in queue.Is it numofshards x some_optimal_number or the number of threads depends on per shard per core basis or is it the average :(numofshards x some_optimal_number + numberofcore)/numberofcore ..
3. Do I even need to worry about parallelism ? Can the single solrcloud server instance to which I initiate by providing all comma separated zookeeper host takes care of the distribution of docs.
4. If at all I am going in complete wrong direction please suggest a better way to improve performance.

Comment: There is a part of your question which is misterious to me, and this is whether the documents are created sequentially. If you don't  interleave document creation and document loading , you cannot gain much from using actors.

Comment: Well my application is basically parsing a **huge event file line by line** (and this process is asynchronous as well) **solr loading is a part of it** . So there is always a continuous flux of lines flowing in whenever a new file is read .

Answer (score 1):

Number of Actors and number of threads is **not** the same thing.  Actors use threads from a pool as and when they have work to do.

The number of threads that can be running concurrently is limited to the pool size which (unless otherwise specifically configured) is dynamic, but typically matches the number of cores.

So the ideal number of pooled actors is roughly the same as the number of pooled threads.

The number of pooled threads, in an ideal world, is the number of cores.

But... we don't live in an ideal world.  An ideal world has no blocking operations, no network or other IO latency, no other processes competing for resources on the machine, etc. etc.

In a non-ideal (a.k.a real) world.  The best number depends on your codebase and your specific environment.  Only you and your profiler can answer that one.

Comment: Agreed with the thread pool part but what about the solrcloud part how does it do the resource sharing and how to make the **loading into solrcloud efficient**